# Why is maxlen set to 256 in Tensorflow text classification tutorial?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

Ref :: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_text_classification

```
train_data = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(train_data,
                                                    value=word_index["<PAD>"],
                                                    padding='post',
                                                    maxlen=256)

test_data = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(test_data,
                                                   value=word_index["<PAD>"],
                                                   padding='post',
                                                   maxlen=256)
```

in the above snippet I am a bit confused why the maxlen was set to 256. I read through the Keras doc and it said that it truncates any sequence longer than 'maxlen'. Why do we need to truncate the length? Just a newbie to machine learning :(

Answer (score 0):

In the dataset, there will n number of training samples. In the context of NLP, these training samples are not guaranteed to be of fixed length. Some may be of length 1024, some may be of length 24 and so on.

The model, that is used in the example needs datasamples to be of fixed length. Inorder to make sure that all the samples are of atleast a minimum length, they will be padded. Here post padding is used.

So, padding makes all the data samples of length like 24, 124 etc and pad it to length minimum needed length. Here the minimum neeeded length is 256. So the data samples with lengths less than 256 will be padded to make it of length 256.

The max_len can be determined based on many factors, It may be due to resource constraints or due to the fact only first 256 characters are relevant for the operation.

Answer (score 0):

256 was a number chosen for the example as it provided the best accuracy. With variable length data the relationship between the length of the data and the accuracy is a bell curve. Too little data and the accuracy is poor, on the other hand if the length of data is too long and padded with a bunch of null values this can mess up the accuracy.

Performance is also a factor, the more data the longer it takes to train the model. With the example you can try different max_len values and observe the results:

```
maxlen Accuracy  Time
64      82%       0m20.817s         
128     85%       0m26.294s
256     87%       0m37.068s 
512     86%       0m57.468s 
None    79%       3m42.411s
```

The longest element was 2494 integers. So None in the table above would be maxlen=2494

Time was gathered using the real value from the Linux time command.